# Subviews of UIView lose transparency

Tags: objective-c, ios, transparency, image-manipulation, alpha

In my program, I have added a UIImageView as a subview of a UIView that has been declared in an xib file. This subview (which contains an image that is a PNG file) should have a transparent background, but the background becomes white when it is displayed on the screen. Is this normal behavior? Is there something I must change to allow the image to display properly? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the background color of your UIImageView and its container UIView.

Comment: Thank you! The issue was the containing UIView's background color.

Comment: what is the background color u set, i already set clear color but its not working fine.......

Answer (score 1):

Each view which should have a transparent background has to be set the background color with `theUIView.backgroundcolor = [UIColor clearColor]`. In your case you should call this on you image view.